# how to find visibility of element / image in calabash

Tags: visibility, calabash, calabash-android

I am working on calabash android with the platform ruby.
And I have to find the visibility of an element / image and it has id and as well only one property ie., enabled , that too always true.

and i tried the options isVisible , isDislayed but am not sure these properties exists

Answer (score 1):

First try this command

```
query("*")
```

If it shows element, then proceed with getting element using ID.

```
query("* css:'#id_name'")
```

The above line will display all the element with ID=id_name.

**Note**: It will show only visible element.

If you need to get all element(visible/hidden), you need use this code:

```
query("* all css:'#id_name'")
```